# Access Datasource inside Bean method injected at other Bean Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In an spring boot project, is there a way to use injected object inside a @Bean method. In my example following, `isdatasourceUse()` method able to acccess injected Datasource (either from dev or war profile)

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Profile({ "dev", "war" })
public class AppConfig {

   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

   @Autowired
   DBPropertyBean dbPropertyBean;

   @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
   @Profile("war")
   public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
      JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
      bean.setJndiName(dbPropertyBean.getJndiName());
      bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
      bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
      bean.afterPropertiesSet();
      return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
   }

   @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
   @Profile("dev")
   public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
      com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource ds = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource();
      ds.setUser(dbPropertyBean.getDsUsername());
      ds.setPassword(dbPropertyBean.getDsPassword());
      ds.setJdbcUrl(dbPropertyBean.getDsJdbcUrl());
      ds.setDriverClass(dbPropertyBean.getDsDriverClass());
      ds.setMaxPoolSize(dbPropertyBean.getDsMaxPoolSize());
      ds.setMinPoolSize(dbPropertyBean.getDsMinPoolSize());
      ds.setInitialPoolSize(dbPropertyBean.getDsInitPoolSize());
      ds.setAcquireIncrement(dbPropertyBean.getDsAcquireInc());
      ds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(dbPropertyBean.getDsAcquireRetryAtt());
      ds.setPreferredTestQuery(dbPropertyBean.getPreferredTestQuery());
      ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(dbPropertyBean.getIdleConnectionTestPeriod());
      return ds;
   }
   @Bean
   public void datasourceUse() {
    //How to user datasource  here
   }

   }
```

Comment: did you try to autowire Datasource then use it in the method?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why method `datasourceUse`? Who would call it? Just autowire a datasource where it is needed. Spring will take care to autowire the datasource depending on active profile. Or do you have both profiles (dev and war) activated at the same time?

Comment: If a class in the spring context you can autowire datasource then use it. You can create configuration class which is @component and you can use datasource.

Comment: You can call `jndiDataSource() ` and use the returned value. Since it is annotated with `@Bean`, Spring will ensure the method content is only executed once and give you the same instance of the bean

Comment: I need datasource instance inside datasourceUse() method, since it is annotated with Bean like others, I  want to be sure  datasource instance is ready to use when it is invoked

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below:

```
@Autowired
public void datasourceUse(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println(dataSource);
}
```